# Items in UITableViewCell changes its position while scrolling upside and downside

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am using `UITableView` to display elements of an `array`. In `UITableViewCell` i used a number of `UILabels` and `UIButtons` to perform actions. Everything displayed well but the problem arise when i try to `scroll` the `TableView` as when i start scrolling each time some `Images` n `Labels` changes their index position. This is first time i am facing this type of issue. I also gone through many Solutions on SO but the issue remains same.

I am sharing my code:

```
    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableItem"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

        NSString* fromDate = [[eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"StartDateTime1"];

        UILabel * nameLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        nameLbl.text = fromDate;

     //First Column

        NSString* titleStr = [[eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Name1"];
        //NSLog(@"%@",spk_about);
        UILabel * spk_aboutLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        spk_aboutLbl.text = titleStr;


        NSString* Description = [[eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Description1"];
        NSLog(@"%@",Description);
        UILabel * DescriptionLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        DescriptionLbl.text = Description;

        NSString* ID = [[eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"ID1"];
        //NSLog(@"-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=%@",compStr);
        UILabel * IDStrLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
        IDStrLbl.text = ID;


        NSString * eventStatus = [[eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Status1"];
        NSLog(@"eventStatus is ..................................................%@",eventStatus);
        UILabel * eventStatusLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:113];
        eventStatusLbl.text = eventStatus;


        rsvpbtn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:111];
        [rsvpbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowRSVP:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rsvpbtn setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        rsvpbtn.tag = indexPath.row;


        mapButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:112];
        [mapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowMap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [mapButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        mapButton.tag = indexPath.row;

        //131
        tickButton1 = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:131];
        [tickButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tickDetail1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [tickButton1 setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        tickButton1.tag = indexPath.row;

        if ([eventStatus isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            rsvpbtn.hidden = true;
            tickButton2.hidden = true;
        }
        else if ([eventStatus isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            tickButton1.hidden = true;
            rsvpbtn.hidden = false;
        }
        else if ([eventStatus isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            rsvpbtn.hidden = true;
            tickButton1.hidden = false;
        }
        else if ([eventStatus isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            rsvpbtn.hidden = true;
            mapButton.hidden = true;
            tickButton1.hidden = true;
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

my `JSON` `Array` response is:

```
{
            "ID1": "11",
            "Name1": "Registration",
            "Description1": "",
            "StartDateTime1": "8:00 AM",
            "EndDateTime1": "8:30 AM",
            "AgendaMapLink1": "",
            "Capacity1": "",
            "AgendaMap1": "",
            "RSVP1": "",
            "TotalGuest1": "1",
            "Status1": "2",
            "ID2": "",
            "Name2": "",
            "Description2": "",
            "StartDateTime2": "",
            "EndDateTime2": "",
            "AgendaMapLink2": "",
            "Capacity2": "",
            "AgendaMap2": "",
            "RSVP2": "",
            "TotalGuest2": "",
            "Status2": "",
            "ID3": "",
            "Name3": "",
            "Description3": "",
            "StartDateTime3": "",
            "EndDateTime3": "",
            "AgendaMapLink3": "",
            "Capacity3": "",
            "AgendaMap3": "",
            "RSVP3": "",
            "TotalGuest3": "",
            "Status3": "",
            "ID4": "",
            "Name4": "",
            "Description4": "",
            "StartDateTime4": "",
            "EndDateTime4": "",
            "AgendaMapLink4": "",
            "Capacity4": "",
            "AgendaMap4": "",
            "RSVP4": "",
            "TotalGuest4": "",
            "Status4": "",
            "ID5": "",
            "Name5": "",
            "Description5": "",
            "StartDateTime5": "",
            "EndDateTime5": "",
            "AgendaMapLink5": "",
            "Capacity5": "",
            "AgendaMap5": "",
            "RSVP5": "",
            "TotalGuest5": "",
            "Status5": ""
        },
```

Comment: Cells are reused. You do a `if (...) else if (...) {} ...`, you need to set the hidden property for each ones in each conditions. Add also an `else {}` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your cell is dynamic cell, means some times subviews of table view cells are hidden. At that time tags not working. You are facing problem with your approach. At this time you need to take a separate class to tableview cell. Give outlets labels and other subviews. Access this cell class in "cellForRowAtIndex" method.

Comment: i am trying this but how to handle button actions in this as i have to put 4 buttons inside a column and i have to create 5 columns inside a tableview cell do you have any code example to handle actions inside tableviewcell

Comment: Ya. I already handle these type of things in myProject. Right now I am unable to share the code. So give btn.tag = indexpath.row; then you can get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you are getting the button with specific tag

```
tickButton1 = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:131];
```

Then you are rewriting button's tag to an indexPath.row

```
tickButton1.tag = indexPath.row;
```

When cell is being reused you can't get the button again, since its tag is now different. Try assingning your indexPath.row to a cell and then getting it back from sender.superview.tag

```
    if (!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableItem"];
    }
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

- (void) ShowRSVP:(UIButton*) sender{
    NSInteger originalTag = sender.superview.tag;
    //Do stuff
}
```